# Recover current OS in case the new one fails

Tags: linux, windows-10, backup

I currently have Windows 10 but late needs make me have to switch to Linux. One thing that I've seen the last time I installed Linux is that it doesn't recognize my networking board.

If this happens again I will have to switch back to Windows (and specifically, Windows 10). BUT what I want to do is that in case Linux won't work properly, recover the current whole Windows 10 (programs, settings, etc.).

Is there a way to do this or should I rather make use of dual-boot to test Linux once again?

Comment: Consider using a live CD of the distribution of your choice. Many of the major Linux distributions offer such versions, which are a good way to test to make sure it will be possible to make your system work. At the very least, it will let you determine that basic graphics, networking, etc can be used. (That said, Linux has pretty good hardware support, unless you are right at the bleeding edge.)

Comment: Laptop or desktop? Booting off a second, independant drive sounds like a good idea here.

Comment: Update: I flashed a Usb with Linux and as I booted from the usb, Ubuntu detected the card so I decided to completely overwrite Windows 10. As for "backing up" the OS, has anyone used Clonezilla and can confirm that it's what I want? (future reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use Linux, then you can try these options `without` having to format/partition/dualboot/etc...

**Option 1:Virtual Machine Apps: [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org)**

Virtualbox is a multi-platform software that lets you run any version for any OS (Linux, Windows, Mac) on any machine virtually! For example, if you have installed Virtualbox on Windows 10, and need to test out [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), then you can download the Ubuntu OS.iso and run virtualbox and it'll let you add a virtual system and install ubuntu on that virtual system via the iso file! That way you can run both windows and linux simultaneously. For the Network configuration, there are different options available in the virtualbox settings for each virtual machine.

**Option 2: Live CD ([Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/))**

In Linux OS's you have the option for booting directly from the CD/DVD into the Linux OS. No setup required to test out the OS. It's similar to a linux system, but linux is not installed until you double click the "Install Linux" icon on the desktop that's booted up from the Live CD. You can try Ubuntu or Linux Mint for this purpose, although many other Linux distributions support Live CD bootup!

**Option 3: Live Bootable USB: [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)**

> Rufus is a utility that helps format and create bootable USB flash
>   drives, such as USB keys/pendrives, memory sticks, etc. It can be
>   especially useful for cases where:
>
> - you need to create USB installation media from bootable ISOs (Windows, Linux, UEFI, etc.)
> - you need to work on a system that doesn't have an OS installed
> - you need to flash a BIOS or other firmware from DOS
> - you want to run a low-level utility

**Option 4: Bootable USB System ([PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/))**

> Easily install your favorite Linux operating system on a flash drive
>   or USB key no larger than your thumb (Thumb Drive). Your Portable
>   Linux operating system can then be taken with you, and run from any
>   computer that can boot from the USB flash device. Bring your operating
>   system, applications, files, email, bookmarked favorites, games and
>   more with you. It's your very own portable operating system you can
>   carry in your pocket.
>
> Pendrivelinux provides simplified information to make it easy for
>   anyone to install, boot, and run their favorite Linux Distro from a
>   portable flash drive!

With Pendrivelinux, you can install a linux OS to your USB Pen Drive, and install programs to it (on boot), and use it like an alternate bootable system! Remove the Pen drive, and you can boot to Windows 10 normally!

Comment: The third option seems to fit my needs in order to test Linux.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comments already given, you can boot the Linux live distribution, run "lsblk"  to figure out which letter your internal hard disk corresponds to (usually sda), then plug a second hard disk that is at least as big as the original.

Using dd if=/dev/sda of=sdb/backup/disk.img

That would create an .IMG image of your windows 10 instalation, exactly copying everything. If you decide at a later date to reinstall windows 10, simply reverse the parameters 
dd  if=/dev/sdb/backup/disk.img of=/dev/sda to reimage your windows 10 install, complete with all partitions, programs, files etc.

Comment: Might work but sadly I do not have a second hard disk at hand. THIS anyway is a solution to what I asked and not just a workaround.